# Change options value in a drop-down list depending on another selected drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem to change the value of the options from the code below, select which changes depending on other select, but I want to change the value of the select id = "numbList", thanks ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   

<select id="diffList" onchange="changeList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Difficulty --</option> 
  <option value="1">Easy</option> 
  <option value="2">Medium</option> 
  <option value="3">Difficult</option> 
</select> 

<select id="numbList"></select> 

<script>
window.difficulty = {};
window.difficulty['1'] = [1,2,3];
window.difficulty['2'] = [4,5,6];
window.difficulty['3'] = [7,8,9];

function changeList() {
    var diffList = document.getElementById("diffList");
    var numbRange = document.getElementById("numbList");
    var selectDiff = diffList.options[diffList.selectedIndex].value;
    while(numbRange.options.length)
    {
        numbRange.remove(0);
    }
    var diff = window.difficulty[selectDiff];
    if(diff)
    {
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < diff.length; i++)
        {
            var difficulty = new Option(diff[i], i);
            numbRange.options.add(difficulty);
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. Do you want numbList to have value of 1-9 instead of 0-2?

Comment: `remove()` does not do what you think it is doing.  You should use `removeChild()` from the parent element instead.

Comment: @mollwe ....yes, I just want to change the value on numbList, because he appears automatically, (0,1,2) is its the value, and I want to change that

Comment: @grochmal [remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) does exactly what OP wants, removing option children

Answer (score 1):

Just use diff[i] for both text and value for option:

```
...
for(i = 0; i < diff.length; i++)
{
    var value = diff[i];
    var difficulty = new Option(value, value);
    numbRange.options.add(difficulty);
}
...
```

As the previous value is removed from select options it selects the first of the new options. So you shouldn't need to set the value of numbList.

To set value of numbList programmatically you could just do `numbList.value = 1;` for example.

Comment: I think it just adds the variable, not change the value

Comment: Now I have lost you, what value are we talking about? For me NumbList.value first has no value then when I select "easy" Numblist.value is 1, when I select "medium", Numblist.value is 4 etc. What am I missing?

Comment: thanks for discussion, sorry if my reply too long... I mean when I select diffList "easy", then select NumbList transformed into "1, 2, 3" when I select diffList "medium", select NumbList transformed into "4, 5, 6" and when I select diffList "difficult", select NumList transformed into "7, 8, 9", and what I mean is to change the value of the NumbList, that is changing the Value of NumbList 1, 2, 3 - NumbList NumbList 4, 5, 6 and 7, 8, 9 ...thanks